# resetting my gcloud application-default client-secret

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, gcloud

I forgot to follow the best practices for setting up my app with gcloud and I accidentally exposed my client-secret somewhere. However when I try looking for the client-secret anywhere in iam or in the gcloud console, I can't seem to find it anywhere.

The client-secret is not tied to a service account, and gcloud auth application-default revoke just deletes and recreates the token, which disables the file for use, but it still has the same client-secret and client-id. I can't seem to edit or delete it with secrets, or through iam or the cli. I can't even find the client-id attached with it in cli either. Does anybody know where to find this or edit it? Or do I have to contact gcp support to have them reset it?

Comment: Have a look here. You should be able to find your credential: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

Comment: I tried using that to locate my credentials, but to no avail. The client-id and my service account client-ids are very different and there is no client-secret or any key that matches the file. I did take a look at it and it seems like the token is the only difference whenever I revoke and grant access again, so I'm hoping just changing it would be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, based on your post, there is nothing to worry about. You have leaked **public** information.

However, you should not be using that Client ID for your own purposes as it is reserved for the cloud CLI. Creating credentials from them can result in API Quota and billing failures.

The Client ID `32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com` and the Client Secret `ZmssLNjJy2998hD4CTg2ejr2` are NOT secrets. It is a special OAuth Client ID assigned for the Google Cloud SDK.

From the Google Cloud SDK `lib/googlecloudsdk/core/config.py`:

```
CLOUD_SDK_VERSION = INSTALLATION_CONFIG.version
# TODO(b/35848109): Distribute a clientsecrets.json to avoid putting it in code.
CLOUDSDK_CLIENT_ID = '32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com'
CLOUDSDK_CLIENT_NOTSOSECRET = 'ZmssLNjJy2998hD4CTg2ejr2'
```

You can review these items at the following [link](https://github.com/twistedpair/google-cloud-sdk/blob/master/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/config.py#L166)

Comment: Hm, this is interesting. It just seems like the token would be the only thing that I shouldn't be leaking? With a client_secret or client_id, is it possible to generate their own tokens as to use or break my app? That would be my only concern. Since it isn't connected to a service account, at least not one that I can see, I'd hope that if someone did have access they couldn't mess around in the project.

Comment: @mtlfmx - Why are you using that Client ID in your app? Create a new Client ID for your app.

Comment: The client id referenced in the python file you mentioned is not what I'm using, it's a different one that comes from when I ran `google auth application-default login`, and taking the file from application_default_credentials.json. I was wondering if leaking or sharing that information would be detrimental but reading into it, it seems like it's almost necessary if I was to containerize my app.

Comment: The Client ID in `application_default_credentials.json` is also a Google managed Client ID that is public information. WARNING: the `refresh_token` is a secret that you must protect. However, **let me repeat**, do not use those client IDs in your application or publish them within containers, etc. Do not publish portions of the CLI `gcloud` authorization files. They are intended for developers and not for app deployment. Either use the metadata service (preferred), or a service account, or issue your own Client ID.